# Bash: Storing command result in variable messes up output

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am in WSL and I try to get the windows username:

```
#!/bin/bash

WINDOWS_USER=$("whoami.exe")
echo "Windows username: '${WINDOWS_USER}'"
```

but the output is kinda scrambled:

```
$ ./createNewUser.sh
'indows username: 'intra\user
```

I actually expected the output `Windows username: 'intra\user'`. But the last `'` is moved to the start of the sentence - how can this happen?

Comment: Did you write the script using a Windows editor that saves its files as DOS text files (with an extra carriage-return at the end of each line, compared to Unix text files)?

Comment: I wrote the script using nano in a WSL shell. If I open the file in Notepad++ there is only a `LF` at the end of each line

Comment: The carriage-return is being output by `whoami.exe`, not the script. `intra\user<CR>` sends the following `'` back to over-write the first column. Check it with `printf '%s' "${WINDOWS_USER}" |  od -t x1ac`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that this command added a `\r` before the final `\n`. It can be removed via:

```shell
WINDOWS_USER=$(whoami.exe | tr -d '\r')
```